# How to fix 'Crypto' exception when running previously working TFS Mac Build Agent?

Tags: macos, xamarin, .net-core, tfs, msbuild

The TFS build agent on my Mac host was working until I recently upgraded Visual Studio and installed PowerShell 6.2.3 using homebrew. The version of Visual Studio Enterprise is now 8.4 (Build 2535).

The build agent was running just before I restarted the Mac host, as per Visual Studio upgrade requirements. The first time I attempted to start the agent again with `. run.sh` on the command-line, it no longer worked. We attempted to install a new agent with the latest build on another Mac host and had similar problems. Is there a breaking change?

I have attempted repairing openssl, as suggested in these links: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/232

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f2f61f67-156e-4163-8cd3-ad882b7bc26d/config-build-agent-faile-on-macsystemtypeinitializationexception-the-type-initializer-for?forum=tfsbuild

I have removed powershell with `brew cask uninstall powershell`

With all of these steps taken, the agent will still not start.

I found logs in the build agent's _diag directory. It appears that the exception occurs when loading RSA commands:

> [2020-01-09 01:01:15Z INFO CredentialManager] Creating type OAuth
>   [2020-01-09 01:01:15Z INFO CredentialManager] Creating credential
>   type: OAuth
>   **[2020-01-09 01:01:15Z INFO RSAFileKeyManager] Loading RSA key parameters from file
>   /Users/Shared/tfsbuildagent/.credentials_rsaparams [2020-01-09
>   01:01:15Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: An error occurred: The type
>   initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception.** [2020-01-09 01:01:15Z
>   ERR  AgentProcess] System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl': The specified module
>   could not be found.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)    at
>   Interop.CryptoInitializer.EnsureOpenSslInitialized()    at
>   Interop.CryptoInitializer..cctor()    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at Interop.CryptoInitializer.Initialize()    at
>   Interop.Crypto..cctor()    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at Interop.Crypto.RsaCreate()    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSAOpenSsl.ImportParameters(RSAParameters
>   parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.RSAFileKeyManager.GetKey()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssSigningCredentials.Create(Func`1
>   factory)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.OAuthCredential.GetVssCredentials(IHostContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.MessageListener.d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Program.d__1.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our on-premises TFS did not have the latest agent binary for OSX, which uses the latest in Mac security instead of using OpenSSL. The new binary is available at [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases). So I downloaded from there instead of downloading from my TFS server.